# nodejs (home) server, and single esp32 for each room

Tags: node.js, esp32

I want to make a nodejs server and the client is esp32 to control rooms at home, such as control of lights, fans, and ac outlets. I am confused about the configuration of nodejs as a client and esp32s as a server or vice versa. how do I choose nodejs as server or as a client?

Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I would make a nodeJS socketIO server and connect every ESP to it's own room on socketIO. That way you can track how many esps are there and display them accordingly on your server's webpage.

**Usefull links:**

- [SocketIO](https://socket.io/get-started/chat)
- [Github Arduino SocketIO client](https://github.com/Links2004/arduinoWebSockets)